# How to send SMS through SNS and Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I am trying to send SMS to my Mobile when my EC2 instance stops.

1. I am automatically stopping my EC2 instance and now I want to send SMS to my mobile when it stops.
2. I created SNS topic with my mobile no. as subscriber.
3. I created an Alarm when the EC2 stops.
4. Under SNS > Mobile > Text messaging (SMS) > Text messaging preferences (Edit):

a. I selected "Default message type" as "Transactional".

b. I created a new IAM role.

IAM role policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:PutMetricFilter",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

SNS topic access policy

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:Receive",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:account-id:sns-topic-name",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "account-id"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-west-2:account-id:alarm:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When the alarm is triggered, I am getting the below error:

```
{
  "actionState": "Failed",
  "stateUpdateTimestamp": 1561102479560,
  "notificationResource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:account-id:sns-topic-name",
  "publishedMessage": null,
  "error": "Resource: arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-west-2:account-id:alarm:alarm-name is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:account-id:sns-topic-name"
}
```

I am unable to understand what permission is it expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is most likely due to the policy having incorrect values. I'm not sure which values you changed to protect sensitive values, but you'd need to update `sns-topic-name` and `account-id`.

However, I would recommend another way of achieving your goals...

You can use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to look out for a specific event (eg an instance changing state to Stopped) and have it send a message to Amazon SNS directly (without using an Alarm).

The steps are:

- In the Amazon CloudWatch console, click **Rules**
- **Create rule**
- **Service name:** EC2
- **Event type:** EC2 Instance State-change Notification
- **Specific state(s):** Stopped
- Choose **Any instance** or **Specific instance Id(s)**
- On the right, under **Targets**, click **Add target**
- SNS topic
- Select your topic

[image: CloudWatch Events - Create Rule]

This will then send a message whenever the instance stops.

Comment: Hi John, I have followed the steps and it worked but for few mobile nos., it's not sending SMS. Is it to do with the Mobile provider or AWS?

Comment: If it works for some numbers, but not every number, then it would be outside your control. AWS Support _might_ be able to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is due to missing permissions on your IAM role for publishing messages to an SNS topic. Make arrangements to attach necessary permissions to the role you use or to the user, like this:

```
 {
  "Id": "Policy1415489375392",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSConfigSNSPolicy20150201",
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:myTopic",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "account-id1",
          "account-id2",
          "account-id3",
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishnu, I changed the Access Policy of the SNS Topic to what you said but it still gives me the same error. Am I missing on something very minor?